# Using Wildcard with Apache Pig Interger Equality Comparison

Tags: apache-pig, wildcard, equality

Is there a way to perform an integer equality comparison in Apache Pig using a wildcard parameter?
For example, I'm trying to Filter data based off a certain integer in the range 1-9.

```
data = load 'path/filename.parquet' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader('number:int');
filteredData = FILTER data BY (number == $numberProvidedByParameter);
```

This code works whenever an integer is provided by the $numberProvidedByParameter parameter variable. However, I would like to have the option to pass in a variable that provides all data, essentially a wildcard parameter that returns true for all numbers. I understand that this essentially defeats the purpose of the `FILTER`, but it seems like a logical route to go when the user is unsure what data they would like to view.

I understand from the [Apache Pig Reference Manual on Comparison Operators](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Comparison+Operators) that you cannot compare an integer to a string using the `==` comparator so is there another way to provide a wildcard that equals any given integer?

I have tried the following inputs to no avail:

```
(number == *);
(number == ?);
(number == [0-9]);
```

Comment: Load it as number:chararray and use regex

Comment: @inquisitive_mind My reducer fails with the message `ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file` when I load with the number field as chararray